# C# Ghostgum/Ghostscript printing delay - status spool

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I'm using the Ghostgum (GSView) that needs the Ghostscript in order to print silently my docs.

The silent print is OK, but printing various docs (pdf docs) stay in some sort of queue that lasts forever and do not print..the one who gets printed (always the first document) goes into some status called "spool" and denies the others from printing.

It's in Portuguese but you can take your conclusions.
[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfDocs.Count; i++)
{
    string file = listOfDocs[i].ToString();

    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (file_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(file), __PATH_TO_SAVE + Path.GetFileName(file), Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

When the download is complete grabs the file and sends it to the GSView to be printed silently.

```
private void file_DownloadFileCompleted(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string filename = args.UserState.ToString();

    using (Process printJob = new Process())
    {
        try
        {
            printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            printJob.StartInfo.FileName = this.__GSVIEW;
            printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-noquery -portrait -printer \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", this.__PRINTER, this.__PATH_TO_SAVE + filename);
            printJob.Start();
            printJob.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            stop("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
           File.Delete(this.__PATH_TO_SAVE + filename);
        }
    }
 }
```

What can I do to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initial for loop, the `DownloadFileCompleted` event is being wired up for every document. The event should only be wired up one time, before the for loop. I suspect the reason only the first document is being printed and remains in the spool is because the `DownloadFileCompleted` event is being fired off multiple times for the same file that was downloaded.

This should clear up the eventing, which may clear up the spool issue:

```
// only declare the event handler once, not for every file downloaded
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (file_DownloadFileCompleted);

for (int i = 0; i < listOfDocs.Count; i++)
{
    string file = listOfDocs[i].ToString();

    // remove from the for loop
    // client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (file_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(file), __PATH_TO_SAVE + Path.GetFileName(file), Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Comment: It seems good and obvious (!!). I'll try tomorrow at work and I'll give you feedback.